# Что означает "щееет"?

Tags: жаргон, обсценная-лексика

Сегодня в Ютубе наткнулся на комментарий: " **щееет** этот звууук,не глуши братан". Начал искать в интернете и еще наткнулся на подобные комментарии.

мне звонил Блев МС и просил скинуть ему битов , значит что-то будет ” у щееет. ..

﻿Поиск приносит содержание неприличного характера.

Comment: ... "oh sh*t"?..

Comment: Это и есть . "oh sh*t"?.

Comment: Серж: извините, я Вас не понимаю. Вы спрашиваете?

Comment: Я спрашиаю:   щееет  -  это  оh sh*t"?

Comment: я не уверена 100% но думаю что это как русский человек на слэнг пишет "sh*t" (хотя звук должен был бы быть короткий в этом слове, я думаю тот кто писал наро́чно (наме́ренно? I mean "intentionally") протянул этот звук, tipo "gangsta style" показать удивление или восторг, whatever... когда была на России, 15 минут стояла и смотрела на неоновую вы́веску над дискотекой "пати". потом русская девочка объяснила мне, что это обозначает "party" : )

Comment: Да, наверное, вы правы. В данном слове i короткий звук. Спасибо. Мне в голову сразу не пришло это слово.

Comment: PD: звук должен был бы быть [ɪ], не совсем понимаю почему автор выбрал "e"

Comment: Серж: здесь к сожалению я не могу ничего сказать потому что воспринимаю на мое ухо этот звук по другому. у нас нет звука "е", у нас е соответствует русскому э : ) я написала бы транскрипцию так [щит]

Comment: Умом Россию не понять.

Comment: Вы правы, я бы тоже так написал. Я вообще это слово как русское читал.Поэтому и не понял.

Comment: @Anonym в среде геймеров, например, довольно часто можно слышать именно "щеет" (оу щеет и т. д.). Почему так — на мой взгляд, это намеренное искажение, что часто свойственно сленговой речи; не стоит забывать и про созвучие со словом "щит", которое могло подтолкнуть к особенному произношению "щеет".

Comment: Aer, но там слышится ***э***, но не ***е***.

Answer (score 1):

Черный прононс слова shit как sheet. Довольно часто можно слышать в видео из гетто и подобных мест.